# Using CDN like Cloudflare with mod_rewrite to save bandwidth

Tags: caching, proxy, cdn, bandwidth, cloudflare

I know CDNs like Cloudflare save bandwidth by caching static files as images, JS, and CSS files.

I have a script that generates images on the fly and its location looks something like this:

```
http://domain.com/image.php?id=1
```

With id being the image id. Cloudflare won't cache these images due to the dynamic URL. If I add a mod rewrite rule to rewrite the URL to become something like:

```
http://domain.com/images/1
```

or

```
http://domain.com/images/1.jpg
```

Will CloudFlare cache the images in this case or the images have to actually be real files that reside in directories?

Comment: This post is a duplicate, it has been answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/791758/using-cdn-like-cloudflare-with-mod-rewrite-to-save-bandwidth/791804#791804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check is to open a page containing an image and then use Chrome Web Inspector. Go to Network > Images, select an image, then under Header > Response header look for cf-cache-status.

If you see **cf-cache-status: HIT** then the image or resource is being cached by CloudFlare. I think the alternative is 'MISS"

Good luck

[image]

Comment: Thanks David for the nice tip! I discovered that CloudFlare has a feature called "Page Rules" to cache normally uncached files like dynamic image scripts as in my case using URL patterns so I don't even have to mod rewrite the URL :)

Comment: thanks for your alternate sugeestiion @MichaelSamuel ... always good to have more than one tool in your tool box ;)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of one on StackOverflow already: [Using CDN like Cloudflare with mod_rewrite to save bandwidth](https://serverfault.com/questions/791758/using-cdn-like-cloudflare-with-mod-rewrite-to-save-bandwidth/791804#791804)

The short answer, however, is this:

> The easiest way to Cache Everything on a given endpoint in CloudFlare
>   is to use a [Cache Everything Page Rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172366-How-do-I-cache-everything-on-a-URL-), an asterisk will match a
>   wildcard result. So in your first example we can do the following:

[image: CloudFlare Cache Everything on endpoint]